# setCursor Method not Working on one MouseListener (Java)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouse, mouselistener

I have a MouseListener for a button that basically says when the mouse enters the vicinity of that button, it changes the cursor to the hand cursor. All my mouse listeners are working fine, but for some reason, this one single mouse listener isn't working. It is identical to all other MouseListeners.

```java
viewAssignments.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // When mouse enters vicinity of a button, sets cursor to hand cursor.
        viewAssignments.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // When mouse exits vicinity of the button, sets cursor to default cursor.
        viewAssignments.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
});
```

Here is the single one that is not working:

```java
about.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // When mouse enters vicinity of a button, sets cursor to hand cursor.
        about.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // When mouse exits vicinity of the button, sets cursor to default cursor.
        about.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
});
```

I am not sure why this one isn't working.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) BTW - we usually add an `ActionListener` to buttons. Your question includes information on *what* you would like the code to do, but not *why.* So ***why*** is there the desire to change the cursor to a hand on mouse over? What is that supposed to indicate to the end user?

Comment: Verify that `about` is the correct instance and one shadowing another.

Comment: You don’t need to add a MouseListener at all.  Just calling `setCursor` will cause the button to show the specified cursor only when the mouse is over that button.

Comment: Thanks setCursor worked fine for each button. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just called `setCursor` method. I didn't need to add a mouse adapter anyway. Thank you `VGR`.

Answer (score 2):

May not solve the problem but don't create custom listeners.

Instead create a generic listener that can be added to any component:

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    }
}
```

Then you add it to each component as required:

```
viewAssignments = new JButton(...);
viewAssignments.addMouseListener(ml);

about = new JButton(...);
about.addMouseListener(ml);
```